# jQuery fadeIn/Out - remove animation from selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gsap

I'm using jQuery and Greensock to create a menu with related content. I'm using Greensock to trigger the initial animation when a user clicks a menu item for the first time. After this, I'm showing/hiding content using jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut functions. The menu items and content are linked using data attributes.

Here's some example HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list-outer">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#" data-content="#content-1">Content 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-content="#content-2">Content 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-outer">
        <div id="content-1" class="content">
            <h2>Content 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sapiente quibusdam, voluptates eligendi officiis possimus autem deleniti, in inventore, exercitationem quidem rem facilis veritatis dolores dolore excepturi minus praesentium officia.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="content-2" class="content">
            <h2>Content 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga nihil suscipit, ex quisquam possimus. Et at debitis magnam sed, ipsam minima nostrum voluptatibus, omnis suscipit esse recusandae qui quis sequi?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Variables

    var listOuter = $('.list-outer'),
        contentOuter = $('.content-outer'),

        moveList_tl = new TimelineMax({paused: true});  

    // Timelines

    moveList_tl
        .to(listOuter, 0.5, {css:{width: "50%"}})
        .to(contentOuter, 0.5, {css:{alpha: "1"}})
    ;

    // Play animation when click the first menu item

    $(".list li a").one("click", function(e){
        moveList_tl.play();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Fade in/out content after the first click

    $(".list li a").on("click", function(e){
        var thisContent = $(this).data("content");
        $(".content").fadeOut();
        $(thisContent).fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Everything works as expected, however when I click a menu item after the initial first click and then click that menu item again, the content fades in/out again.

I'd like the content to stay in place if a user clicks the current menu item again - without any animation. If there's a solution that rolls everything into Greensock - even better.

Here's an example pen showing my current state: http://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/YZvEjO/

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Do the fadeIn/fadeOut stuff only if the content is not already visible.

```
$(".list li a").on("click", function(e){
    var thisContent = $(this).data("content");
    if(!$(thisContent).is(':visible')) {
        $(".content").fadeOut();
        $(thisContent).fadeIn();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

for this to work you have to hide the content on startup:

```
.content {
    ...
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the flickering when clicking on an already active/visible element, you can disable the fading out of this particular element, by targeting it with its id. What you do now is fade out all elements with the class `content`, you can change it to fade out all elements except the element that has been clicked.

You will still apply fadeIn() but it won't have any effect on the active element since it's already visible.

```
$(".list li a").on("click", function(e){
    var thisContent = $(this).data("content");
    var id = $(thisContent).attr('id');
    $(".content:not(#"+id+")").fadeOut();
    $(thisContent).fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```